# Instantiating object from C# from C++ using tlb reference not working

Tags: c#, c++, com

I am trying to call a c# method from a c++ program.

I managed to get a working example of what I want running locally from visual studio by following this movie (even though its in japanese)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8h1upGiG4HQ

With this I got the following c# class.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace test
{
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IMyClass
{
    int GetData(String t);
}
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public int GetData(String test)
    {          
            return 3;          
    }
}
}
```

Locally I can call this class with this c++ program.

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <Windows.h>
  #import "C:\Debug\test.tlb" no_namespace


  int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
    CoInitialize(NULL); 

    IMyClassPtr obj;
    obj.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MyClass));
    printf("data=%d\n", obj->GetData(" ")); 
    CoUninitialize();

     return 0;
 }
```

But when I try to get this working in a bigger program.
In this case a sample credential provider that I then make into a dll-file and put in the system32 catalog.
The dll builds fine and the credential provider starts fine but when I create the obj it is null.
The Createinstance return "class not registered"

Relevant code in the credential provider.

```
  #include <Windows.h>
  #import "C:\Debug\test.tlb" no_namespace

  .....

  CoInitialize(NULL);
  IMyClassPtr obj;
  obj.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MyClass));                            
  if (obj == NULL) {
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "NULL", "", MB_OK);
  }
```

This return null if I run it on log in.
I have no idea how all this works so hopefully there is something obvious I need to do.

Comment: CreateInstance() has a return value, an HRESULT.  If you don't check it then you can't know why it failed.  We can't either.  You'll have to improve your error reporting to get ahead.  Most common issue is that a credential provider normally needs to be a 64-bit executable but you only registered the 32-bit version of your C# DLL.   Use the 64-bit version of Regasm.exe to fix.

Comment: Hi
It returns "class not registered"
Im not sure about the 32-bit part. Both computers use 64 and it works locally. But maybe this can be it anyway?
I built the C# project from inside visual studio, dont see any options there for 32/64 and dont know what Regasm.exe is.

Comment: If I'd ask "Did you register it correctly" and you'd say "I'm not sure" then that always means "no" when you get a "Class not registered" error.  Use Regasm.exe

Comment: Hmm. I do not understand unfortunately.
I stopped using a different machine and now use the credential provider on the same machine where I got the test application to connect to the C# tlb in the first case.
But with same effect. Is it because the working one is calling from inside visual studio that means it does not have to be registered in that case.
Anyway if anyone understands Regasm and has a clue how to register a com-tlb please post a line.

Comment: Hello again
I have gotten further now so created a new question to reflect that but it got marked as duplicate so I will continue here instead.
I have now gotten the project to work locally.
I used this tutorial instead of the japanese movie to create and register the c# project:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736
and made sure I did everything in x64.
However when I upload this dll to another computer I get class not registered where the c# project is called from inside the c++dll.
Do I need to run a regasm.exe command on every computer that is going to use the dll?

Comment: I'm flat out of ideas how to convince you that you need to run Regasm.exe.  Yes. yes, yes, yes.  Really.  Yes.

Comment: OK well you dont have to convince so much as helping me understand I think.
I did use Regasm to create the tlb file for the c# project.
But are you telling me I also need to run a regasm command(another command I would assume) on every computer that is going to use the completed c++.dll?
Because that sounds strange to me, but if you tell me that is the case I will believe you.

Comment: Well I did it. Kind of. But still dont understand.
I put the c#dll on the other computer and ran the same regasm command there, creating the tlb file on htat one as well and now it does work.
But surely this cant be right?
The c++dll that I built already contains the c#dll so why would I need to put the c#dll on every computer and create the tlb locally?
What I am missing?

Comment: OK I realize now that I was mistaken on one key point. The c++dll do not have the c# project built in the way I thought. It calls it when needed. I could have sworn I had tried to remove the c# dll after building the c++ and that it still worked but I must have been mistaken.
So my hopefully last question. What if the computer I want to have this on do not have visual studio? Regasm will not exist then right? Does this mean I cant call my c# project?